# Django Rest request.data object empty

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have trouble getting the data from an ajax request.I can access the data through Djangos' request.GET (and other POST, DELETE etc. headers), but not with the REST request.data (or request.body) which returns an empty dict.
My ajax call:

```
function getMeal(event)
{
  var tmp       = event._id.split("_")
  var database  = tmp[0]
  var mealId    = tmp[1]
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'updateEatenMealAjax' %}",
      data:
      {
          'database': database,
          'mealId'  : mealId,

      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
        $('#update_EatenMeal_FormBody').html(data);
      },
      dataType : 'html',
      async: 'false',
      contentType: 'application/json'

    });
}
```

My django view:

```
@login_required
@api_view(["PUT", "GET", "DELETE"])
@csrf_protect
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def updateEatenMealAjax(request):

    args = {}
    eaten_object = None
    # WHICH DATABASE DOES THIS FOOD ITEM BELONG TO
    database = request.data.get('database')
    mealId  = request.data.get('mealId')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Django-REST-framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/):

> **request.data** returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard `request.POST` and `request.FILES` attributes
>
> **request.query_params** is a more correctly named synonym for `request.GET`.
>   For clarity inside your code, we recommend using `request.query_params` instead of the Django's standard `request.GET`. Doing so will help keep your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may include query parameters, not just GET requests.

As long as you pass data into your views through [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), irrespective of the verb that you use (be it `GET`, `POST` or any other), they will be available in your `request.query_params`  instead of `request.data`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and additional explanation. The problem was solved in a sec. Thanks again.